# Dependent Interactive Reports

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

I have 2 interactive reports in one page. I want to implement the functionality that on selecting a row in first interactive report (parent) based on one table, the same key which is present in another table upon which another Interactive Report (child) is based upon, is passed to child interactive report, and data is updated in the child interactive report.

Data in child interactive report should refresh upon selecting another row in parent interactive report.

How can I implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using Interactive Grids where you have Master/Detail relationships? See this blog post: https://blogs.oracle.com/oraclemagazine/easy-masterdetail